# How to run OptiFine and shaders at the same time in Minecraft for PC?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc, mods, minecraft-optifine

I've installed the GLSL Shaders profile for Minecraft 1.8 without using Forge, and it works fine. However, since now I'm not using OptiFine, I'm getting a rather large decrease in FPS, which is disappointing.

Is it possible to install OptiFine and GLSL shaders at the same time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of OptiFine `1.8.8 HD U F2` ([changelog](http://optifine.net/changelog?f=OptiFine_1.8.8_HD_U_F3.jar)) shader support is integrated, that means, you no longer need to install Forge and GLSL Shaders mod to have shaders in-game.

The shader options are the same as they used to be, same UI and same capabilities, - shaders work exactly like they would in GLSL Shaders mod.

Comment: Can confirm that this is correct.

Comment: And so can I :D [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/uLHlINg.png)